# Can you use spmetal entities for FAST search?

Tags: fast-search, search

Is there a good site for FAST search information, complete with sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably know, SPMetal generates entity classes for LINQ for SharePoint. Most of the classes generated are used to translate LINQ syntax to CAML.

Since FAST doesnt use CAML (it uses Fast Query Language -FQL) for queries, SPMetal cant be used to search FAST.

Here are some links to get you started.

[FAST Query Language (FQL) Syntax Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394606.aspx)

[Querying FAST Search Server 2010 for SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394622.aspx)